# How to configure Zurb Foundation in a VueJS TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to incorporate Zurb Foundation v6.5.3 into a TypeScript based VueJS project created w/ @Vue/CLI. The jQuery type definitions are included project. In the following component Foundation is initialized with the $(document).foundation() command.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  components: {},
  mounted: () => {
    $(document).foundation();
  },
})
export default class Layout extends Vue { }
</script>
```

However, the following message is displayed when compiling the project which prevents it from running.

*Property 'foundation' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.*

Version: typescript 3.4.5, tslint 5.16.0

Has anyone experienced this problem or found the proper way to incorporate Foundation into a VueJS TypeScript project?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you need to add

```
import 'foundation-sites';
```

after

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and it will load all the Foundation modules. Alternatively, individual modules can be initialized.

If this is done in App.vue then all child components will have Foundation initialized.